# Behavior of dpkg -S when the argument starts with a slash

Tags: dpkg

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/doc/tasksel-data  # fine  
dpkg -S  usr/share/doc/tasksel-data  # fine  
dpkg -S     /share/doc/tasksel-data  # not found  
dpkg -S      share/doc/tasksel-data  # fine  
dpkg -S        are/doc/tasksel       # fine
```

Why on Earth does the third line above fail? Note that line one starts with a slash(`/`), so that seems unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: But line 1 is the actual absolute path. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not documented as far as I can tell but a leading `/` makes `dpkg` treat the argument as a path and not a pattern. In other words, if you tell it to search for something that starts with `/`, it assumes it should look for a file in one of the installed packages with that *exact* path.

You can confirm it easily enough with

```
$ dpkg -S nonmatching
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *nonmatching*
$ dpkg -S /nonmatching
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /nonmatching
```

Note that in the first case, with no `/`, the error shows that it searched for `*nomatching*`, while with the `/` it searched for the exact path `/nonmatching`. For example, it also fails to find `/doc` despite the existence of directories like `/usr/share/doc`:

```
$ dpkg -S /doc
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /doc
```

---

While I can't find any mention of this in the man page, I did confirm by checking the source. The following lines are from the `searchfiles` function defined in `querycmd.c` (dpkg 1.17.13)

```C
if (!strchr("*[?/",*thisarg)) {
  varbuf_reset(&vb);
  varbuf_add_char(&vb, '*');
  varbuf_add_str(&vb, thisarg);
  varbuf_add_char(&vb, '*');
  varbuf_end_str(&vb);
  thisarg= vb.buf;
}
```

That will add `*` around the argument passed unless that argument begins with a `/`. So, that causes `dpkg-query` to treat anything starting with `/` as an absolute path and anything that doesn't as a pattern to be matched.

Comment: That could not be make more clear. Personally I think it should stick to 'matching pattern' searches, as the 'exact path' seems pointless, especially when '*' is implied at the end of the string  anyway.

Comment: @rayandrews it's not. Anything that starts with a `/` is treated as a specific string to search for, not a pattern. Anything else has `*` added to the start and end. This is not implied, it is done explicitly in the lines I show and only for strings that don't start with one of those characters. This is actually very useful, for example, `dpkg -S /bin/bash` will tell me which package installed the specific executable found at `/bin/bash` while `dpkg -S bash` will return all matches. I can easily imagine situations where I want one or the other.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. You know, if this was only documented properly there would be no problem :(